# Codeigniter в url появлятся document_root

Tags: php, codeigniter

суть проблеми вот в чем 
сайт работает прекрасно по ссылке http://127.0.0.1/ и остальних, но только следует добавить еще один слеш в конец(http://127.0.0.1//) и происходит вот что... вообще не имею понятния из-за чего

[image: и да, 404 слизал у гугла]
.httaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '127.0.0.1';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: Попробуйте  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`.
Ну а вообще если не полениться то можно погуглить и найти много статей по этому делу https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&biw=1920&bih=937&ei=XCMRXYX2KoOMmwXwtYvIBQ&q=codeigniter+htaccess+remove+double+slash+from+URL&oq=codeigniter+htaccess+remove+double+slash+from+URL&gs_l=psy-ab.3...66111.70352..70928...0.0..0.228.1252.0j7j1......0....1j2..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i131j0j0i67j0i203j0i10i203.z7YF4DvV-Ag

Comment: Как вариант 

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]`

Comment: вкратце, проблема не в файлах а в сервере, а точнее  в конфиг файлах virtualhost так как у меня бил не одни хост а несколько, а 127.0.0.1 имел строку  <VirtualHost  *:80  localhost:80 127.0.0.1:80 > 
Исходя из этого я просто создал новый  VirtualHost на ip 127.0.0.n  и !просто переместил туда файли !без изменений. Все заработало.  З.Ы  найду причину поломки отпишу.